# Ember Mirage persist data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli-mirage

Currently, when I delete or change some records (model), I can see `HTTP` requests that intercepted by `Mirage`, and data on page really changes. But after page reload - it returns back. Is it possible to configure `Mirage` somehow to avoid rollback data after page reload, and allow me to do it manually?

Comment: What do you mean after page reload? Are you running this within an acceptance/integration test or are you just running the code locally (non-test environment)?

Comment: locally, development.

Comment: Do you have this issue when you transition from one route to another or only on page reload?

Comment: only page reload, like Cmd + R

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your issue is that Ember Mirage is being reloaded on the page reload (which makes sense).

You will want to create your own server that your frontend will connect to that maintains fake/mock responses and can persist the data. You can use something like fake-server or [MockServer](http://www.mock-server.com/) or just write your own code in Node/Ruby/Python/whatever language that fakes the REST API for your Ember app. This is the only way to maintain persistent data since your Ember app is short-lived within a browser.

Comment: Alternatively, I suggest using the localstorage or localforage addons, which might be enough.

Comment: @locks that's also a possibility though I'd be worried about cross-browser testing and deployability (we have our server running tests).